# whitespace after \parencite with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, white-space

when using `bla bla bla \parencite{citation_key}.` with `biblatex` I always get a space after the citation. It would look like this:

> bla bla bla (authorname 2010) .

I'm using the package `biblatex` like this:

```
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear, style=authoryear-comp,sortcites,
sorting=nyt, firstinits=true ,sortcase=false,url=false, 
isbn=false,doi=false,clearlang=false,backend=biber,
uniquelist=false,maxcitenames=1,bibencoding=ascii]{biblatex}
```

What can I do to get rid of the whitespace?

minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,openright]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{scrhack} 

\usepackage[nohyperlinks,printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear, style=authoryear-comp, ,sortcase=false,url=false, isbn=false,doi=false,clearlang=false,backend=biber,uniquelist=false,maxcitenames=1,bibencoding=ascii]{biblatex}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchbibmacro{name:andothers}{%
  \bibstring{andothers}%
}{%
  \bibstring[\emph]{andothers}%
}{}{}%

\urlstyle{sf} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ltxtable} 
\counterwithout{table}{chapter} 
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter} 
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{upgreek}


\usepackage[title]{appendix}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage[vlines]{tabularht}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{todonotes} 
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{nth} 
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage{syntonly}
%\syntaxonly

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}

\externaldocument{background}
\externaldocument{results}
\externaldocument{m&m}
\externaldocument{discussion}
\externaldocument{anhang}


\newcommand*\rot{\rotatebox{90}}
\newcommand*\OK{\ding{51}}

\newcommand\T{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}       
\newcommand\B{\rule[-0.9ex]{0pt}{0pt}} 


\hyphenpenalty=10000
\exhyphenpenalty=10000
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\nobibliography*

\usepackage{filecontents}



\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Huar2015,
title = {{some title}},
volume = {43},
year = {2015},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\newcommand{\src}[1]{|\tiny{\textsc{Source:} #1}} % 


\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}


\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A0}{ }
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{FFFD}{ }
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2060}{ }
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2192}{ }
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{221E}{ }

\begin{document}
\sloppy

this is a dummy text. this is a dummy text. this is a dummy text. this is a dummy text. this is a dummy text  \parencite{Huar2015}⁠. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Normally there should be no space after a `\parencite`. I could not reproduce your problem in a test I just did. Can you please prepare an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) that is fully self-contained and shows the problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I can't reproduce the issue. Please, add a minimal example. By the way, I get warnings about `firstinits` being deprecated (use `giveninits`) and `<namepart>inits` conflicting with `uniquename=full`.

Comment: Note further that `citestyle=authoryear, style=authoryear-comp,sortcites,
sorting=nyt,` is redundant, `style=authoryear-comp` alone is enough.

Comment: Which language are you using with `babel`?

Comment: Any news here? Please show us a full MWE that we can use to reproduce your problem. If you can't give an example that shows the issue, I will vote to close your question as unclear. It cannot be answered with additional info.

Comment: Unfortunately, your MWE misses the `.bib` file. When I used a file that is available on my machine I could not reproduce the issue. If you can't reproduce the problem with the code you showed, it must be some other bits you haven't shown us.

Comment: In your actual document where the problem occurred do you get the space after all citations? Or only if you cite certain sources? How do these entries differ from the others where the problem does not occur? Do you have other code related to `biblatex` in your file?

Comment: I provided the whole preamble now. The space occurs when \parencite is followed by a period.

Comment: For some reason you have a word joiner (U+2060) in `\parencite{Huar2015}⁠.` between the closing brace and the `.`. (You can see this is you move your cursor from behind the `.` to the left, you have to move twice to get from the `.` to `}`.) I have no idea where that came from, but it must be from your editor or similar. It is not included by `biblatex`. `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2060}{ }` then makes a space of the zero-width character. So a quick fix is `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2060}{}`. But really you have to find out who puts the joiner there.